# API for in-season food info based on location

Tags: api, food

I have found some APIs to determine when foods are in season but they most a secondary feature and not very accurate. Their geographic area will be as large as the United states. I need something for local food shopping.

Comment: Although it won't be 100% accurate, it might be worth trying to find food harvest times by growing zone, and then look at what growing zones are near a given location.  (and further south; I've heard that a greenhouse effectively shifts your growing zone as if you were 100 miles closer to the equater for my region; and you can double up greenhouses ... so if you're looking for 'local to support the community', that might be worth tracking.  If you're looking for 'inexpensive because it's local', maybe not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be offered as data, but it would be exceedingly easy to scrape this [Eat Local resource](http://www.simplesteps.org/eat-local) from NRDC. There's a page for each state which lists foods by month.

For each state they have "learn more" links, which probably also lead to their data sources (few of which appear to be structured data.)

Comment: I'm surprised that they treat california as one area ... I'm guessing you'd have a significantly different growing zone between norther & southern california.

Answer (score 1):

you could try usda farmer's market api.
"listings to include: market locations, directions, operating times, product offerings, accepted forms of payment, and more"
read more here:
http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/